# How to get a red asterisk in a <string> entry

Tags: android

How do you get a red asterisk in a  entry so that you can display it at the end of the text to indicate its a required field, like: Enter your name * (asterisk will be red). Or, for that matter, anywhere within the text.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can't do that through xml string resources. This can only be done via code. For this you need to use [`SpannableStringBuilder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableStringBuilder.html) and [`ForegroundColorSpan`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ForegroundColorSpan.html).

---

Here is small example:

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

String simple = "Enter your name ";
String colored = "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(simple);
int start = builder.length();
builder.append(colored);
int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, 
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

text.setText(builder);
```

---

[image]

Comment: This worked exactly as needed: thanks!
A related question with the Stack Overflow process in general:
I was only able to increase the point count from 1 to 2 for the answer: do you have to have a certain privilege in order to award more than just a few points?

Comment: No, nobody can award more then one point per question/answer. Treat it like voting: you either vote for it, or against it. If you have question regarding how stackoverflow works, visit meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/;

Comment: How did you add that extra space though? I am assuming you didn't use `" *"` as string.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/commontasks.html#selectingtext) for examples on how to style portions of a textview. Here's how you could do it for a red asterisk.

```
EditText editTxt = new EditText(this);
editTxt.setText("Testing asterisk *");
Spannable str = editTxt.getTxt();
int loc = editTxt.getTxt().toString().indexOf("*");
str.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), loc, 1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative for showing asterisk in android Textview

```
txtvw2.setText(Html.fromHtml("<sup>*</sup>"+"enter you name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize variable in strings.xml `<string name="date_of_incident">Date of Incident <p><font color="red">*</font></p></string>`

Answer (score 0):

Write into strings.xml file

```
<string name="KeyWord">KeyWord <font color='red'>*</font></string>
```

this helped me solve this problem.