# Set color to part of EditText placeholder

Tags: java, android

I have a mandatory `EditText` that has a placeholder with mandatory symbol `*` that has to be red. Help with this guys.

[image: Like this]

Comment: what do you have and what did you try?

Comment: I have tried to make an adapter with two TextViews, and the one to have red color and make some ugly set visible things on click...

Comment: i meant to say, post some code. i will not do your homework if you're not willing to do any effort. but some guy did so you're lucky i guess

Comment: I am trying his answer now. Let you know here if it works. 10x Bart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this, try this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456588/how-to-get-a-red-asterisk-in-a-string-entry) for more detail.

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

String simple = "First Name ";
String colored = "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(simple);
int start = builder.length();
builder.append(colored);
int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, 
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

text.setHint(builder);
```

Comment: This is the answer, 10x Remees M Syde for the help. I will edit your answer only on one place to be perfect. text.setText(builder); becomes > text.setHint(builder);

Comment: Mohammed Ali, we are not joking here :-P

Answer (score -1):

Create your own custom view with its structure like

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="40dp">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="100dp" 
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:id="@+id/placeholder_left"
        android:text="First name"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="40dp" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/placeholder_left" 
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:text="*"/>
```

Add logic to handle the visibility of the "placeholder" TextView upon text change in the EditText.

Comment: 10x for the help Patrick Chan, but Remees M Syde's answer is better for me.